# GUID + Auto-Increment ID = Slow Performance?

Tags: performance, database-design, primary-key, guid, unique-key

One of [Jeff Atwood's](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) cons of using a GUID is that it is

```
Cumbersome to debug (where userid='{BAE7DF4-DDF-3RG-5TY3E3RF456AS10}')
```

And I agree. I was thinking, now that 16-byte ID's are no longer considered an enormous undertaking, are 16-byte + 4-byte ID's a practical compromise?

You could apply clustered indexes, and do most of your serial (read: optimization) work on the auto increment IDs. The merging, distribution, or other massive undertakings would use GUIDs as its main workhorse.

So...anybody out there try mixing the best of both worlds? What were the results of your undertaking? Of course, there is the issue of having a PK (GUID) eating up all your index space next to another indexed field (the auto-increment ID), so I imagine the tradeoff might be delicate and/or specific to a very narrow scenario.

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714458/using-both-a-guid-and-an-auto-incrementing-integer) has addressed the issue before, but from the standpoint of managing referential integrity. I am simply curious as to how I could combine the combinations of PK/UK configurations on a table, and their various impacts on performance and scale. In essence, is it best to use the GUID as a PK, and an auto-increment as a non-unique index? Is it better to make them a unique key as a pair?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing an `int` is cheap, and useful. Indexing a `GUID` is expensive (and secure from a web-facing front; nobody is going to be able to cycle through `GUID`s to request individual rows from a table). `SEQ GUID`s do provide (relatively) fast index builds after lots of inserts, but eliminates most of the "randomness" that can provide some security for public access.

From this [discussion on SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/28/sql-server-guid-vs-int-your-opinion/), the eventual progression from `int` -> `bigint` -> `guid` is a rare one, and shouldn't be taken into consideration until the time calls for it. By far, your safest and most accessible method for starting a new project is to use a `bigint PK AUTO_INCR`, with a `GUID` as a non-indexed, non-sequential field specifically for sharding or merging shechmas throughout the life of the database. It takes a hit up front in terms of speed, but those affects won't be felt until you have enough rows to actually care about things like cross-instance uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with auto-increment IDs is insert performance: if you insert thousands of rows, it means thousands of auto-increments at the database level. On the other hand, index insertion is not a problem, hashing methods ensure a generally good distribution.

You could use, for instance, a random number of 20 digits as the primary key and use that only: no need for a GUID!